# $timeout use inside AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I used AngularJS factory to create new instance model for my project, and each model contain a progress value that will be incremented, paused, and set back to 0 based on "start", "pause", and "stop" user actions.

```
app.factory('ModelA', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    function ModelA(progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    };

    ModelA.prototype = {
        startProgress: function() {
            this.counterFunction();
        },
        counterFunction: function() {
            this.progress++;
            if(this.progress == 100) {
                this.progress = 0;
            }
            //console.log(this.progress);
            //console.log(this.counterFunction);
            progressTimeout = $timeout(this.counterFunction, 1000);
        },
        // Haven't tested the method below
        pauseProgress: function() {
            $timeout.cancel(progressTimeout);
        },
        stopProgress: function() {
            $timeout.cancel(progressTimeout);
            this.progress = 0;
        }
    };
    return ModelA;
}]);
```

For some reason, when I call `startProgress()` in the `ng-click` expression function, the progress will increment 1 and then stop. I added logs to check `this.counterFunction` for every call. I realized it only prints out `1` and the whole `counterFunction` on the first time. As for the second time, `this.progress` will be `NaN` and the counterFunction will show `undefined`.

I'm new to AngularJS, could someone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: If anyone encounters this issue in the future, I recommend look at both answers that posted by @BrianHsu and Lihau Tan to help you understand the `setTime` and `this` topic better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` object in the function called by the `$timeout`, i.e. `this.counterFunciton` is not the `ModelA` instance, therefore you should use
`$timeout(this.counterFunction.bind(this), 1000)` instead.

You can read up this [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/) about binding `this` object in JavaScript.

A working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRGjvg?editors=1111) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The execution context `this` changes when the $timeout gets executed. You would need to preserve the ModelA `this` in $timeout(this.counterFunction.bind(this), 1000). You bind and pass the `this` to this.counterFunction and thus counterFunction has the right access to this.progress.

Check here more info about the `this` problem here. $timeout is the wrapper for window.setTimeout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer and article!